# Using CAST with an insert into ... select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to cast some bad data into proper data using `CAST(column AS DECIMAL(7,2))`, which works when just SELECTing, but once combined with an INSERT statement, the statement fails:

```
/* setup */
drop table if exists dst;
create table dst (
  id int not null auto_increment
  , columnA decimal(7,2)
  , primary key (id)
);

drop table if exists src;
create table src (
  id int not null auto_increment
  , columnA varchar(255)
  , primary key (id)
);

insert into src (columnA) values ('');

/* test */

/* This works as I would like it to*/
select CAST(columnA AS decimal(7,2)) from src; /* returns 0.00 */

/* This fails */
insert into dst (columnA)
select CAST(columnA AS decimal(7,2)) from src; 
/*0 19  21:01:56    insert into dst (columnA)
 select cast(columnA as decimal(7,2)) from src  Error Code: 1366. Incorrect decimal value: '' for column '' at row -1   0.000 sec*/
```

> Edit: this is a pared down reproduction example - the data I am
>   working with is much more varied than just an empty string - it might
>   also be a non-numeric string value or a numeric value that is outside
>   of the bounds of decimal(7,2) - in which the `CAST` statement works
>   the way I would like it to when only in a `SELECT` but fails when
>   trying to use them as part of the `INSERT`.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to achieve what I am looking for?

I am using MYSQL 5.6.11 on WIN 7 x64

Comment: @notulysses I'm not sure I follow - columnA is not null, it is an empty string.  I did try it though and received the same error.

Comment: I am having this exact issue, none of the answers actually address the problem - why can I select with a CAST and see the correct decimal values, but when adding the INSERT INTO part the cast fails (the destination column is of the same decimal type as the CAST is set to...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set explicitly the value for the empty string with `CASE` or `IF`:

- `SELECT CASE WHEN columnA = '' THEN 0 ELSE CAST(columnA AS decimal(7,2)) END 
  FROM src;`
- `SELECT IF(columnA <> '', CAST(columnA AS decimal(7,2)), 0) 
   FROM src;`

Or use 2 `SELECT`s with `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT CAST(columnA AS decimal(7,2))
FROM src 
WHERE columnA <> ''
 UNION ALL
SELECT 0
FROM src
WHERE columnA = '';
```

Comment: The CASE statement would work - I am hoping for a better solution though.  The CAST when used in an insert also fails when the value is too large to fit in the decimal or if there is non numeric data in the column, even though the normal select behavior works the way I would like it to (returns 0.00).

If I don't find a better solution though I will use the CASE statement and will accept your answer.

Comment: What's wrong with `CASE` and you want a "better" solution? (you could also use `CAST(CASE WHEN columnA = '' THEN 0 ELSE columnA END AS decimal(7,2))`

Comment: Because `CASE` only works for specific values - The `CAST` works the way I would like it to with values such as `abc` or `123456.78` - but fails when using it with the `INSERT` statement.  I can't add a case for every possible value that will cause this to fail. You aren't wrong, it just isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: @notulysses in the case of an empty string or non-numeric value, 0.00 would be fine.  In the case of a too large value, I would prefer the largest value that the `DECIMAL(7,2)` can hold, 99999.99, but would take 0.00 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `REGEXP` to filter out any irregularities in source data:

```
INSERT INTO dst (columnA)
SELECT CAST(CASE 
               WHEN columnA REGEXP '^[0-9]{0,7}(\.[0-9]{0,2})$' THEN columnA 
               ELSE 0
            END AS decimal(7,2)) 
FROM src;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8b613/1)